# Watson Discovery service create_collection() api call returns Error 415: Unsupported Media Type

Tags: python, watson-discovery

I'm using the `DiscoveryV1` python library to try to create a new collection in my WDS environment. I have the following code:

```
from watson_developer_cloud import DiscoveryV1

discovery = DiscoveryV1(
username = "username goes here",
password = "password goes here",
version = "version goes here")

conf_id ='valid configuration_id'
env_id = 'valid environment_id'
new_col = discovery.create_collection(env_id, 'TestV2', configuration_id=conf_id)
```

The final line of the above block throws the following error:
`watson_developer_cloud.watson_developer_cloud_service.WatsonException: Error: Unsupported Media Type, Code: 415`

Full stack trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "uploadCorpus.py", line 23, in <module>
    new_col = discovery.create_collection(env_id, 'TestV2', configuration_id=conf_id)
  File "/home/Vito.Colano/Apps/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/watson_developer_cloud/discovery_v1.py", line 227, in create_collection
    accept_json=True)
  File "/home/Vito.Colano/Apps/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/watson_developer_cloud/watson_developer_cloud_service.py", line 324, in request
    raise WatsonException(error_message)
watson_developer_cloud.watson_developer_cloud_service.WatsonException: 
Error: Unsupported Media Type, Code: 41
```

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be a bug in the Python SDK for Discovery. I, just now, opened a pull request to fix it.
https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/python-sdk/pull/223

I forgot to say *Thank you* for asking this question. I only went looking for this bug and figured out what to fix because of your question.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Bruce.